# How to add type metadata element in the OPF file?

Tags: epub3

I added following in the `OPF` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0" xml:lang="en" unique-identifier="pub-id">
<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:type>ePub</dc:type>
</metadata>
```

but getting error by **Epub validator**. http://validator.idpf.org/

```
element "dc:type" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag or element "dc:contributor", "dc:coverage", "dc:creator", "dc:description", "dc:format", "dc:identifier", "dc:language", "dc:publisher", "dc:relation", "dc:rights", "dc:subject", "dc:title", "link" or "meta"
```

**How to add `type` metadata element in the `OPF` file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Package Document (.opf)**

The Package Document contains information about the book including the metadata, manifest, and

spine. It also defines the version must be 3.0.

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="bookid" version="3.0" prefix="rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/#">
```

The Metadata

Minimum, you must include the following items.

- Title
- ID
- Language
- Type
- Modified-date

For Example:

```
<dc:title>XXXXXX</dc:title>
<dc:creator>YYYYYY</dc:creator>
<dc:source>0000000</dc:source>
<dc:identifier id="p0000000">URN:ISBN:0000000<dc:identifier>
<dc:publisher>ZZZZZZ</dc:publisher>
<dc:language>en</dc:language>
<dc:type>Text</dc:type>
<dc:format>100 pages</dc:format>
```

Comment: yes, upvote, yes, I have all metadata in OPF. I will check 2maro again and get back to you..